# How to stream data into the chain of operations

Tags: java, streaming

I am trying to stream word from one operation to another. In other words, think as I have three classes and their operations namely `Cleaner.eraseDublicate()`, `Matcher.detectCityName`, `Tokenizer.concatenate()`. Moreover, I have one big hash table, `word, frequency` as key,value. 
I want to build a streamed operations like shown on the sketch. That is, `Tokenizer.concatenate()` will read first five entries on the hash table, and do its own operations; afterwards, stream its results to the `Cleaner.eraseDublicate()` in order to erase dublicate. Furthermore, result of the `Cleaner.eraseDublicate()` will be streamed to the `Matcher.detectCityName()`. 
How can I connect those operations and fetch only five entries and stream them to the chain of operations?

```
             Tokenizer.concatenate() Cleaner.eraseDublicate() Matcher.detectCityName()
------------           ----------           ----------           ----------
| hash     | ------->  |        | ------->  |        | ------->  |        |
|   table  |           |        |           |        |           |        |
------------           ----------           ----------           ----------
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is here.  Just write code that does what you just described.

Comment: Are you using Java SE 8? The new Stream API should make the solutions for these kind of problems easy...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth which point you find unclear?

Comment: @zeynep: What's not clear is which part of this you're stuck with.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The problem is that, *iteratively* take words from hash table and stream them to the operations. I donot know how to create the connection between them.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth instead of calling, I try to create pipeline sort of connections.

Comment: That will still involve calling things.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth same?

Comment: If using Java 8, just `stream` and `map` and `filter`. Easy. If using Java < 8 then use `Future<>` to set up a pipeline. Of Guava's `FluentIterable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what you really want, but I think that [Pipeline Design Pattern](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=366887&seqNum=8) is what you need. It is designed for Parallel programming and only found in the [Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.informit.com/store/patterns-for-parallel-programming-9780321228116?w_ptgrevartcl=The+Algorithm+Structure+Design+Space+in+Parallel+Programming_366887).

Briefly, it consists of **stage** and **qeueu** structure. Each Stage takes data from preceding queue and put into next queue. Importantly, BlockingQueue is used for the purpose of blocking if data is not available in the queue.

Anyway, read the blog post, and let me know if you have a question.